# How to initialize a CCTMXTiledMap manually?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I would like to know how a CCTMXTiledMap can be initialised without the tiledMapWithTMXFile function so I can set values like tile indicies and texture via hand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported by cocos2D. You need to create your own code for that.

Comment: Yep, made my own tile map system.